# When Delete the row using javascript then, first time only deleting correct row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

For gridview, rowdatabound event, I wrote below code:

```
Private Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "<a href='javascript:fnDelete(" &  e.Row.RowIndex & ");' style='text-decoration:none;'><img src='Images/DEL.gif'   height='10' width='10' border='0'></img></a>"
```

Now on fnDelete function as below in JavaScript:

```
 function fnDelete(rowindex)
 {
  ....
    var gridViewctl = document.getElementById('<%= gv.ClientID %>');
    gridViewctl.deleteRow(rowindex+1);
 }
```

Problem: First time, it deletes correct row and after that each time, it delete some different row instead of deleting that clicked row. It looks, reason is due to rowindex is binded before and row were delete so, its change.

Can you please guide how to fix the issue.

Comment: Why you are calling the Javascript method from `RowDataBound` ? It will iterate automatically for each row before the page renders.

Comment: yes. it will iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not get the rowIndex dynamically instead of passing it using the element from the event and finding the parent TR.

```
e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "<a href='#' onclick='fnDelete(this);' style='text-decoration:none;'><img src='Images/DEL.gif'   height='10' width='10' border='0'></img></a>"

 function fnDelete(el) {
     var gridViewctl = document.getElementById('<%= gv.ClientID %>');
     // anchor is el, td is the first parentElement, tr is the next parentElement
     var rowIndex = el.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
     gridViewctl.deleteRow(rowIndex);
 }
```